# encrypting form data before submitting to server

Tags: django, apache

I have developed a Django application and now want to make sure the POST data transmitted through the page is safe.

I have couple of questions about this?

1. I see SSL certificates being displayed on many webpages. How do I get this certificate?
2. Do I need to change anything on my submitted form to encrypt the data or should I change any settings on my webserver?

I know its a general question but it would be great if someone provides a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the POST data transmitted through the page is never safe from an application perspective.  You don't have control over the user of the website.  SSL and HTTPS helps prevent man in the middle attacks to ensure the request from the client (browser) to your server is encrypted.  The underlying data that is sent can be malicious, so you should always validate inputs.

Secondly, if you want to use HTTPS and SSL, which I highly recommend, you'll need to obtain a certificate from one of the providers out there and install it with your webserver, which I presume is apache.  Typically your domain provider can help you with obtaining an SSL certificate for your domain from one of the main certificate authorities.  Regarding the installation and setup, there is tons of information about this online as it's a common task.  I'm not familiar with Apache configuration to provide any specific recommendations.  You'll also want to have rewrite rules so that your site can only be accessed via HTTPS and if someone tries to use HTTP, it simply redirects to HTTPS.

Lastly, you don't need to do anything in your Django application as your webserver should handle the basic interactions between your server and client to validate the HTTPS requests.